# Quarkus Cache Eviction Listener

Tags: caching, quarkus, caffeine-cache

Any one has an idea if there is a way we can add an eviction listener to Quarkus Cache?

https://quarkus.io/guides/cache

It seems to use Caffeine cache underneath and Caffeine cache has capability to have an eviction listener added. Any idea, why it's not provided as an option in the Quarkus cache configuration?

https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-cache_quarkus.cache.caffeine.caches-config-additional-configuration-applied-to-a-specific-caffeine-cache-highest-precedence

Comment: You might open a feature request on their github. I don't see them discussing it, maybe just never came up.

Comment: sure, thank you!